# tooltipster pass dynamic data from php array to tooltip via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tooltipster

I'm using Tooltipster with ajax request to display dynamic data from php when I hover tabledata stored in an array. To get the content of the elements I use a jquery function (shown below) and it works as expected. (The alert outputs the correct content)

But my problem is, that the code only passes the first array value to tooltipster but I want tooltipster to get the value of the hovered element, just like in the alert output, to do a query with the hovered content of the tabledata in 'tooltip.php'. Here is my code:

```
$('.tabledata').mouseover(function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    //alert (content);

$('.tabledata').tooltipster({
        position: 'left',
        content: 'Loading...',

    functionBefore: function (origin, continueTooltip) {

    continueTooltip();

    if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'tooltip.php',
            data: { id: content},
            success: function (data) {
            origin.tooltipster('update', data).data('ajax ', 'cached');
        }
      });
    }
   }
 });
});
```

I'm new to jquery and appreciate any suggestions...

Comment: The solution is simple, I just had to replace '$('.tabledata').tooltipster({'                                   with '$(this).tooltipster({'                                        and everthing works fine ;)